# What is the punishment for buying ammo after being involuntarily mentally hospitalized?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

It seems to me this could be misdemeanor or felony but I'm not sure.

So states have background checks which seems like the right answer.

Comment: You haven't mentioned a jurisdiction.

Comment: Virginia really any state with out background checks

Comment: Unaswerable without more info. For example: How long ago was the hospitalization? Was the hospitalization a court-ordered commitment? Are you concerned with state or federal criminal liability? If state, which state? (States have different systems of penal liability) What type of "ammo" and how much? I would vote to close for "requires more details or clarity," but the bounty makes closing unavailable.

Comment: How could it be more serious than a felony?  There isn't a more serious class of crime.  This is the class that includes premeditated murder.  How could buying ammunition (under any circumstances) be more serious than premeditated murder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virginia state law imposes restrictions on possession and transportation of firearms and ammunition, [§18.2-308.2](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacodefull/title18.2/chapter7/).  That law restricts those who have been convicted of a felony, as well as those committing certain juvenile offenses. Separate laws, 18.2-308.1:1 et seq, address purchase, possession, or transportation of firearms by persons in various "mentally impaired" states. 18.2-308.1:3 specifically addresses involuntary commitment.

> It shall be unlawful for any person (i) involuntarily admitted to a
> facility or ordered to mandatory outpatient treatment pursuant to §
> 19.2-169.2; (ii) involuntarily admitted to a facility or ordered to mandatory outpatient treatment as the result of a commitment hearing
> pursuant to Article 5 (§ 37.2-814 et seq.) of Chapter 8 of Title 37.2,
> notwithstanding the outcome of any appeal taken pursuant to §
> 37.2-821; (iii) involuntarily admitted to a facility or ordered to mandatory outpatient treatment as a minor 14 years of age or older as
> the result of a commitment hearing pursuant to Article 16 (§ 16.1-335
> et seq.) of Chapter 11 of Title 16.1, notwithstanding the outcome of
> any appeal taken pursuant to § 16.1-345.6; (iv) who was the subject of
> a temporary detention order pursuant to § 37.2-809 and subsequently
> agreed to voluntary admission pursuant to § 37.2-805; (v) who, as a
> minor 14 years of age or older, was the subject of a temporary
> detention order pursuant to § 16.1-340.1 and subsequently agreed to
> voluntary admission pursuant to § 16.1-338; or (vi) who was found
> incompetent to stand trial and likely to remain so for the foreseeable
> future and whose case was disposed of in accordance with §
> 19.2-169.3...

Okay, that is *who* the restriction applies to. Now, the prohibition is

> to purchase, possess, or transport a firearm. A violation of this
> subsection shall be punishable as a Class 1 misdemeanor.

"Firearm" means firearm, and "ammunition" is ammunition: they are subject to different laws. The felon possession law makes possession of ammunition illegal because the law refers to "firearm, ammunition for a firearm, or a stun weapon". The "involuntary commitment" law only restricts firearms, not ammunition. The background-check law 18.2-308.2:2 only regulates firearms purchases. See also [this analysis of Virginia ammunition law](https://lawcenter.giffords.org/ammunition-regulation-in-virginia/), confirming that felon-in-possession is the one restriction on ammunition.

[Federal prohibitions (18 USC 922)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/922) do include prohibitions on ammunition sales, see especially

> (d) It shall be unlawful for any person to sell or otherwise dispose
> of any firearm or ammunition to any person knowing or having
> reasonable cause to believe that such person—...(4) has been
> adjudicated as a mental defective or has been committed to any mental
> institution;

and

> (g) It shall be unlawful for any person—...(4) who has been
> adjudicated as a mental defective or who has been committed to a
> mental institution...to ship or transport in interstate or foreign
> commerce, or possess in or affecting commerce, any firearm or
> ammunition; or to receive any firearm or ammunition which has been
> shipped or transported in interstate or foreign commerce.

The penalty is in [18 USC 924](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/924):

> (2) Whoever knowingly violates subsection (a)(6), (d), (g), (h), (i),
> (j), or (o) of section 922 shall be fined as provided in this title,
> imprisoned not more than 10 years, or both.